# clearInterval() isn't stopping an interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Alright, before you mark this as a duplicate, please read the entire thing.

So, I'm new to JS. I'm trying to make a timer. Whenever the function `timerReset()` is called, an interval is supposed to be restarted. I have this:

```
intervalID = setInterval(wallsPingTimer, wallsTime); //INTERVAL IS DEFINED ON STARTUP
wallsTime = 10000;
wallsToggle = true

function timerReset() {
    if (wallsToggle === true) {
        console.log('Timer has been reset');
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        intervalID = setInterval(wallsTimerPing, wallsTime);
    }
    if (wallsToggle === false) {
        console.log('Timer is disabled');
    }
}

function wallsPingTimer() {
//some code
}
```

The timer is started on startup `intervalID = setInterval(wallsTimerPing, wallsTime)`, but the old timer never stops. What ends up happening is `wallsTimerPing()` is being executed on multiple timers over and over again. The `clearInterval(intervalID)` never actually stops the original, and I'm confused.

I've looked through a lot of other similar questions, and it seems like I'm doing this right (obviously not). Whats going on?

Comment: `setInterval()` takes a function reference as its first argument. What is `wallsTimerPing`? Please update your question to show all the related code.

Comment: Code shown looks right. How are you using `timerReset` and how are you concluding interval isn't reset?

Comment: the clearInterval is followed by a setInterval in your code so the wallsTimerPing function will never stop executing

Comment: @ScottMarcus Updated, wallsTimerPing is a function. 
@charlietfl ``timerReset`` is executed by other functions. This is a bot in discord.js, so when a certain command is used it is executed.

@Stakvino the timer is supposed to be restarted, thats intentional. That part works, the old interval just keeps running...

Comment: You defined wallsTime AFTER you use it?

Comment: @epascarello wallsTime is defined at the beginning of the script, I put it at the top here to show that.

Comment: Still not showing where `wallsToggle ` gets changed or how you call timerRest. Really need a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: How do you know its the old timer that is still running, and not the new one, you're clearing the old one and then immediately passing on the same values to the new one. Post your complete code if you're looking for some help.

Comment: Sounds like you need to show the actual code.

Comment: Please see my updated answer which goes into detail as to what, exactly your code is currently doing and shows two patterns to successfully get your timer working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you only check `wallsToggle` for `true` or `false` (and potentially stop the timer) when `timerReset` first runs and that function kicks off your timer, which then calls `wallsTimerPing`, but `timerReset` doesn't run ever again and therefore the `clearInterval()` to stop the running timer never gets hit.

Here it is step-by-step:

1. `wallsToggle` is set to `true`
2. `timerReset()` gets called
3. `wallsToggle` is tested for `true`
4. `wallsToggle` is `true` and so the `true` branch of the `if` is entered
5. `"Timer has been reset"` is logged
6. `clearInterval()` is called but no timer has been started yet, so nothing happens
7. `setInterval()` is called and when the interval has elapsed, `wallsTimerProg()` is placed on the event queue and a new interval count is started.
8. The second `if` statement is executed, but `wallsToggle` is still `true` so its `true` branch is not entered.
9. `timerReset()` completes.
10. `wallsTimerProg()` executes.
11. Something may or may not happen in `wallsTimerProg()` that sets `wallsToggle` to `false`
12. `wallsTimerProg()` terminates
13. The interval is reached and step 7 happens again.
14. When the call stack is idle, steps 10-13 happen again.
15. Step 7 followed by 14 continue forever because `wallsTimerProg()` has no code that clears the timer.

Your pattern would be correct if the timer was recursively calling `timerReset` because the if/then tests would be run upon each call to the function and the `clearInterval()` would potentially get hit.

```js
let intervalID;
wallsTime = 2000;
wallsToggle = true


function timerReset() {
    console.log("wallsToggle is: " + wallsToggle);
    
    // The code that determines if the timer should continue should 
    // be in the function that will be called repeatedly.
    if (wallsToggle === true) {
        console.log('Timer has been reset');
        intervalID = setInterval(timerReset, wallsTime);
    } else  { // <-- If a Boolean isn't true, it must be false. No need to check
        // Clear the interval when you've determined that you need to stop
        clearInterval(intervalID);  
        console.log('Timer is disabled');
    }
    
  // The main code that this function does here
  // along with something that would change wallsToggle to false
  wallsToggle = false;
}

timerReset();
```

But, if you want/need a second function to be called by the timer, then you need to move the code that determines if the timer should run again into the function that the `clearInterval()` calls, not the function that runs once and starts the operation.

Here's an example of how it should work:

```js
let intervalID;
wallsTime = 2000;
wallsToggle = true

function wallsTimerPing(){
    console.log("wallsToggle is: " + wallsToggle);
    
    // The code that determines if the timer should continue should 
    // be in the function that will be called repeatedly.
    if (wallsToggle === true) {
        console.log('Timer has been reset');
    } else  { // <-- If a Boolean isn't true, it must be false. No need to check
        // Clear the interval when you've determined that you need to stop
        clearInterval(intervalID);  
        console.log('Timer is disabled');
    }
    
  // The main code that this function does here
  // along with something that would change wallsToggle to false
  wallsToggle = false;
}

function timerReset() {
   intervalID = setInterval(wallsTimerPing, wallsTime);
}

timerReset();
```